Export Dash LeafletMap as HTML
I'm lookig for a way to make a dash leaflet map downloadable as a html file in a plotly dash dashboard. I found some examples for plotly plots in dash (e.g. https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/ or Export plotly dash to html from callback) but I do not know how to transform and save a dash leaflet MapContainer element as an html object.
As a starting point, I created the following example which fails when trying to export the map, as the value of map_children is not a string.
from dash import html, Input, Output, State, Dash
from plotly.io import to_html, to_json
import dash_leaflet as dl


external_css = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css"
icon = dict(
    html='<div><span> 10 </span></div>',
    className='marker-cluster marker-cluster-small',
    iconSize=[40, 40]
)

map = dl.Map([
    dl.TileLayer(),
    dl.DivMarker(position=[56, 10], iconOptions=icon)
], center=[56, 10], zoom=6, style={'height': '50vh'}, id="my_map")


app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[external_css])

app.layout = html.Div([
    map,
    html.Button("Export Map", id="export-button", n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id="export-link"),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("export-link", "children"),
    [Input("export-button", "n_clicks")],
    [State("my_map", "children")],
)
def export_map(n_clicks, map_children):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        export_filename = "exported_map.html"

        with open(export_filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(map_children) # TODO how to export the map?

        return f"/{export_filename}"
    else:
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


at this moment only idea: create own HTML with leaflet as string, and use f-string to add elements from map_children to have full HTML - and later write it in file. So you would use "template with HTML"
